# Magento css and js are not loading properly after migrate to cloud server

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have recently migrated the website (https://www.chennaicrackersonline.com/) from shared server to cloud server. The website is developed in magento 1.9.0.1 using mysql.

After moving the magento files and database to the cloud server, the website css and js are not loading properly. After given the proper permission for the css and js folder also, not resolved the issue.

While checking the page source, it appears that the css were merged and js were merged. Please refer the screenshot for the better understanding below:

[image]

When I check the page source, I could see that there is "m" folder and "1497249376" folder. Actually these folder are not exist or not created properly in the respective location. It is applicable for the js files also. Js files also resides inside "m" folder. But there is no "m" folder physically.

I am not sure what is the exact issue and how to resolve this issue? Is there any permission issue or any plugin /module causes this issue? Can you guide me / help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable JS and CSS merging until you figure out the problem.
For Magento 1.x go to admin panel > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer.
Make sure you are using Default Config for Current Configuration Scope (dropdown menu at the top in left sidebar).
Go to JavaScript Settings and CSS Settings and set the Merge options to No.
Reset Magento cache and browser cache, then reload your page.

Comment: Thanks @Marian for your reply. I just checked the admin panel of magento. It seems to be the same issue (js and css are not loading) on the admin panel too.

Is there any other way to resolve this issue using phpmyadmin (mysql query) to set the Merge options to No?

Comment: @Vinayagm : Use phpMyAdmin to acces your database and search for `core_config_data` table. Open the table and export / download a copy to your PC in case you need a backup later. Search the table for `dev/js/merge_files` and `dev/css/merge_css_files` path fields and change the corresponding value fields from `1` to `0`. This should unmerge your CSS and JS. Also delete the contents of `/var/cache` folder in your Magento installation to clear the existing cache.